# Get the JDK version which is eclipse using to compile my current projects

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, java-7, java-6

I want to know which JDK is eclipse using to compile my current projects.
Is there a way to know that from eclipse itself.

Comment: Eclipse has its own Java compiler.

Comment: @greg-449 how to know it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse has its own Java compiler, it does not use the JDK compiler.

The 'Preferences > Java > Compiler' preferences set which language level the Eclipse compiler uses.

You can also override this for individual projects in the 'Java Compiler' Property page for the project.

The 'JRE System Library' setting in the 'Java Build Path' properties for a project determine which JRE is used for the Java system library Jar files.

Answer (score 0):

Open the project and look next to its JRE System Library folder to see the version. For example in one project mine is JDK1.7.0_51.  If that does not work, then right click on the project name, select Build Path/Configure Build Path and see the configured JDK version in the window that pops up.  Each project can be independently configured to use a different JDK, but one of them is the default and that can be configured in the Configure Build Path app.